# Rmagick each_pixel, how does it work?

Tags: ruby, pixel, rmagick

I need to manipulate each pixel of an image in rmagick. I am doing this in IRB(interactive ruby) This is what I have:

```
require 'Rmagick'
include Magick
f = Image.new(100,100)
f.display #so far so good. A 100x100 white image is displayed

f.each_pixel {|pixel, c, r| pixel.red = 0}
f.display #the image is still white. It should really be a shade of blue.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The thing is, the array you get back from each_pixel is a new dataset.  The data needs to be stored back to the image.

Use get_pixels and store_pixels instead:

```
img = Magick::ImageList.new('img.jpg').first
pixels = img.get_pixels(0,0,img.columns,img.rows)

for pixel in pixels
    avg = (pixel.red + pixel.green + pixel.blue) / 3
    pixel.red = avg
    pixel.blue = avg
    pixel.green = avg
end

img.store_pixels(0,0, img.columns, img.rows, pixels)
img.display
```

Comment: Ha! Forgot about this, googled the same problem, and found this :) Thanks again Bryce :)